# laravel homestead and npm errors

Tags: laravel, npm, homestead

Im using laravel homestead 0.5.0, I have a fresh install laravel but whenever i try to do npm install--no-bin-links or npm install on the VM or on Powershell or CMD it always give an error.

Maximum call stack size exceeded.  windows max path length i guess? anything I can do to avoid this? heres my package.json

```
    {
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
     },
    "devDependencies": {
     "gulp": "^3.9.1",
     "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
     "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.0"
     }
   }
```

im using windows 8.1 and virtual box 5
node version is 5.12.0
npm version is 3.10.5

any help is appreciated thanks

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSncy.png)